# Java, multi class instance variable referencing

Tags: java

```
public class FrameViewer
{

    String csvName = "none";
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Which file would you like to open?" + " A - asia.csv" + " B - europe.csv" + " C - africa.csv");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String csvName = input.next();

        if (csvName.equals("A"))
            csvName = "asia.csv";
        else if (csvName.equals("B"))
            csvName = "europe.csv";
        else if (csvName.equals("C"))
            csvName = "africa.csv";
        else
            System.out.println("You havent chosen a file.");
```

between here is where im having a issue, I was going under the assumption that when canvas was created below, the CountryComponent class would reference the 'csvName' from the choice made,  inside the CountryComponent methods, but it didnt

im absolutely lost right now, i wanted to try passing the choice along as a parameter into the getData method, but I couldnt figure out how to pass along the choice itself, I kept getting a error

I left in the instance variable csvName in the component class because it may be causing a issue, but idk, it wouldnt let me compile without it.

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(750, 650);
        frame.setTitle("Country Data");
        CountryComponent canvas = new CountryComponent();
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Component class

```
public class CountryComponent extends JComponent
{

    // instance variables

    String csvName;   

    public void CountryComponent()throws IOException
    {

        getData(); 

    }

    public void getData()throws IOException
    {
       ...
```

this is what I tried, well the last try, ive done tried like 20 different things to try and get the information to actually get displayed.

```
 public void CountryComponent(String test)throws IOException
{
    String csv = test;
    getData(csv); 

}

public void getData(String csv1)throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        csvName = csv1;
        File csvFile = new File(csvName);
```

which compiled but this line in the FrameViewer class gave the error

```
CountryComponent canvas = new CountryComponent(csvName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) has to be without `void`. It does not have return type.

```
public CountryComponent() throws IOException
{
...
}

public CountryComponent(String test) throws IOException {
...
}
```

Comment: I feel really dumb right now, i left void in there because i thought I needed it because it wasnt returning anything, just calling up the other method to retrieve the information